# Group by average intervals across a timeframe

Tags: mysql

So let's say that I want to keep track of my CPU temperature, with simple columns 'date' and 'temperature'. I'd like to see what period saw the highest temperatures on average in the last week. I capture the data every 10 minutes, so I want each 10 minute block averaged with the same block from the other days of the week.

So for example:

```
2018-01-08 02:00:00 78.3
2018-01-08 03:00:00 81.2
2018-01-09 02:00:00 74.1
2018-01-09 03:00:00 75.9
```

I would want the averages of each day @ 02:00:00, each day @ 03:00:00, and so on. (except the real data is every 10 minutes) The exact datetime varies - it's not always 02:00:02, sometimes it could be 02:00:07, etc., so I can't just do an exact conditional.

Any idea how I'd go about making this data? I assume there's some way I can use GROUP BY for this, but I'm lost as to how.

Comment: You can format the date to have hours and 00 for minutes and then group by that and use the average function to get the average for that hour. If you can show the table structure, then I can help with the query as well.

Comment: You can use `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetimecolumn, "%Y/%m/%e %H")` to get just the hour variable and group by this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Format just the hour and minute, and group by that.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%H:%i') AS time, AVG(temperature) AS temp
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY time
```

This assumes that the readings are never delayed by more than a minute from the expected 10-minute periods -- if the reading for `02:10` happens at `02:11:01` it will not be put in the group.